# Typescript unpacking arguments to overloaded function

Tags: typescript, overloading, argument-unpacking

Just to illustrate what I mean by "unpacking", consider the following example

```
function simpleFunc(a: number, b: string): void { /* ... */ }
function simpleProxy(args: [number, string]) {
    simpleFunc(...args)
}
```

This works just fine, with typescript mapping [number, string] to (a: number, b: string). I have a use-case where I have to do something similar with a more complex function which has overloaded signatures, like so:

```
function overloadFunc(name: string): void
function overloadFunc(name: string, content: number): void
function overloadFunc(content: number): void
function overloadFunc(name_or_content: string | number, maybe_content?: number): void {
    /* ... */
}
```

Now I can't make unpacking to compile. I tried this:

```
function overloadProxy1(args: [string] | [string, number] | [number]) {
    overloadFunc(...args);
    //           ^^^^^^^
    // Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0 or more.(2556)
    // ... An argument for 'name' was not provided.
}
```

And this:

```
function overloadProxy2(args: [string | number, number?]) {
    overloadFunc(...args);
    //           ^^^^^^^
    // Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
    // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
}
```

Is there a way to make this work ? If not, is this documented somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is this lovely `Parameters` type utility:

```js
// This way if you want to call it like overloadProxy1(['name'])
function overloadProxy1(args: Parameters<typeof overloadFunc>) {
  // ...
}

// Or this way if you want to call it like overloadProxy1('name')
function overloadProxy1(...args: Parameters<typeof overloadFunc>) {
  // ...
}
```

[Link to TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=23&pln=24&pc=17#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHAbgUwE4Bs4EMAmAYuBABRi4C2aAXIgM5QYxgDmAlHSnDPgFChIsBMnTY8REuSq0GTFqwA0iCAihowUOmBCUARpk6JuvASWFJUmHAWKRSqzRq2Id%20w1x79B0eJbE2kvYU1AD6cBihjuqadIzMbIgAPq66BhhGJt7mfqLWEnZkIWjhkdHOcfKJKW7pypS4AJ4GUWrOAPzaaR7GXogA3nyIw4gA9ABUiAB0M4jjo3wAvnxmQrlW4gQAChhwAB6NAIykuBis9HRbpzLqGPQAPFCNAA5ocMB5m0EQAHzsA0MRhtAoVSDMpqdzuwANyA4ajUYjJFIgB6aPRKLhY0RAFE9q9oGh8IhDgBaABMiEhumc9GUehAUEQrDgTIADMgMIhKBE0FNSOSAKyCgBs7CxCOmswAgkhqdRNIhgBFEAByYqqxAAd1w9FcrMQz12KF4RKmSxWPgsn0CO32jXJJzOF0QVwwN0wDyer3eNoKJD%20AKRwP99nBkPoMIliORyIx6OjiGlZxpit93rQaviCmSqXcGE1MD1YANuvoMFYFD0WEzUDghuu1FuyA%20GazVVYqvNSMlABUXpn1d0C4gi-qmWWK1Wa4g67OB%202Ep3%20eSAMwAFkF4uWfBD212B2OAG11TJVQBdKN7-B2w%20kI8iy-QoA)

[Link to documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst)